# GTA SA graphics problem

Tags: graphics, games, amd-graphics, playonlinux

I have problems trying to play GTA San Andreas using PlayOnLinux. The game starts fin, but when I begin a new game, the graphics look really weird, similar to this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0z3lVWFr7vg.
The game is obviously unplayable.
My card is an ATI Radeon HD 5870, and Im using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, 6 GB of RAM.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: There are some items on the POL Forum which you should read. 
https://www.playonlinux.com/en/search.html
It could be your solution lay there.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and I managed to solve this problem on Zorin OS 12 (which is based on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, so it should work for you too).
First I upgraded my Wine version by entering the following command in Terminal:

```
sudo apt install wine-stable
```

Then I upgraded to the newer Linux kernel and graphics support stack with the following command:

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04
```

After this GTA San Andreas was running perfectly.

Comment: It also fixed me another problem with the resolution. After exiting the game, the resolution was set to very low and I couldn't change it without restart. This fix solved me that too.